# How do I exclude a particular class from a CSS property?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to not apply hoover on one of my CSS class with the :not() selector.

```
.left-menu-sidenav a:not(.selected):hover {
    background-color: #6689E6;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```
<div className="left-menu-sidenav">
    <a href="/">
      <img alt={"left-menu"} className="left-menu-logo-image selected" src={left_menu_logo}></img>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have a lot of  tag in my page and I have to keep this logo in the "left-menu-sidenav".

What did I miss to exclude the *hover* from this particular class?

Comment: be more specific with your question ??

Comment: What does this sentence **mean**? *"I have to keep this logo in the "left-menu-sidenav""*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `a:not(.selected)` is rereferring to an `<a>` tag selector but your HTML code has no class at all, only the `<img/>` within it has a `selected` class.

Consider why your image has this class, what toggles it. 
Probably it should be moved to the parent `<a>` tag